# Can we merge both these tags, [android-glide] and [glide-image-library]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

These two tags [android-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-glide) and [glide-image-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide-image-library) are  referencing the same library [**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

- [android-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-glide)

  A fast and efficient open source image loading library for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.
- While the [glide-image-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide-image-library) tag has no usage guidance

I think we need to merge these two tags because both are used for questions related to [**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Questions tagged [android-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-glide) :  1,106 questions

Questions tagged [glide-image-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide-image-library) :  121 questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few issues here which had to be cleared. There were 122 questions in the [glide-image-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glide-image-library) tag, out of which

- 109 had [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.
- 8 had other android related tags.
- 1 was something unclear - [How to use the Glide library with Azure Blob Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854946/how-to-use-the-glide-library-with-azure-blob-container)
- 4 were related to Laravel Glide, which I have tagged with [php-glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-glide), a tag which was already present.

Now that the tag is clearly used just for Android Glide questions, I have synonymized and merged the tags.